# python ctypes keyboard events' arguments

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, keyboard-events

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0x0002, 0)
```

presses and holds Ctrl key.
I want to know what arguments to pass for all possible keyboard events.

Comment: Start with the right function -- [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310). `keybd_event` has been deprecated for about 15 years. It only queues one key event at a time, so it can't guarantee that an input sequence is queued contiguously, i.e. other input sources can end up interleaved in the queue.

Comment: eryksun, thank you for your answer. Could you give a code example of how keybd_event can go wrong.

Comment: The interpretation of a key or key sequence depends on the sequential order and the state of key modifiers such as shift, ctrl, win, and alt. If multiple threads are writing to the keyboard input queue simultaneously, including the user typing at the keyboard, the end result is indeterminate and probably a mess.